# Hangfire Service Not Running

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, background-process, hangfire

I am trying to use Hangfire for background job in my ASP.Net Core 7 Web API project.
When I start the application and look at the console logs, it shows the following

[image]

which appears that the hangfire starts but my application never sends the email it is meant to send.

I call the service as follows:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => SendEmailConfirmationToken(sentToken, newUser));
```

And when I check the Hangfire dashboard I see the job enqueued but never executed

[image]

These are the packages and the versions of Hangfire that I have in my application

```
 <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.8.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.8.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.PostgreSql" Version="1.19.12" />
```

But when I do this,

```
Task.Run(async () => SendEmailConfirmationToken(sentToken, newUser));
```

The email get's sent.

So, I know the problem is not from the SendEmailConfirmationToken() method;

How can I get this resolved please?

Comment: U have a server processing the queue that the job is queued under?

Comment: First of all, does it work with a simple action rather than this email one? Secondly, you are passing in objects that are going to get captured by the lambda, it is much safer to let DI handle the work and do something like `BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IEmailSenderService>(x => x.SendEmailConfirmationToken(sentToken, newUser));`

Comment: @Jawad, I am trying it on my local machine. It has always worked in my previous applications but I am not able to figure out why it is not working on this particular project

Comment: @DavidG This `BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IEmailSenderService>(x => x.SendEmailConfirmationToken(sentToken, newUser));`  did not work either. I also tried this `BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("I executed this one"));` and it did not work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just discovered that I omitted the following line in the program.cs file while adding the hangfire service to my application

```
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();
```

That was the issue.
I have added it and Hangfire is working as expected now. Thank you for your efforts to help